# Is there a way to reset search in Mail?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, email, search

I'm not sure how everyone is doing this. But I do roughly 20-30 mail searches a day.

But when the search is done and now I want to see the top of my most recent email (for new emails and whatnot). How do I get there?

There's no keyboard shortcut to do this. And if I were to do this manually I have to press the X in the search field. Scroll the email list to the to top by using the scroll bar. It's really cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone comes up with something better than this, but…

- X-out the search - this awkwardly leaves you in the now empty search box rather than in the mail list.
- Select any mail in the list. [Or hit Tab until you get back into the list. Depending on how you have your tabbing set up that could be three presses, or about 10:\ ]
- Press Home [or Fn/Left Arrow if you don't have a dedicated Home key]
- Select the top mail.

Basically, with this method all you're gaining is the Home key-press to get you back to the top. The rest is still very manual.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion two:

Set up an empty folder. I put one "On My Mac", haven't tested elsewhere.

After you're done with your search, click on the folder.

There's nothing in it to auto-select & it clears the search.

When you click back to your regular Inbox, the last message you selected before the search is now re-selected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I could find without using the mouse:

1. press <kbd>cmd-alt f</kbd> to focus on search field
2. press <kbd>esc</kbd> to clear the search
3. press <kbd>cmd-1</kbd> to go to first favourite mailbox.

(for this I added a smart mailbox containing all recent mails and made it a favourite)